# A String.prototype.diff() implementation (text diff)

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, strings, edit-distance

I just had the idea to develop an algorithm to calculate and highlight the difference between two strings. I know that there are already some libraries to do the job but I just tried to make my own. I really don't know whether this one is similar to the existing ones but it seems to work fine. As of now it's still in it's early stage which means depending on the situation it sometimes produce some multiple consecutive deletion and insertion spans which probably require a second pass to consolidate them under two single delete and insert spans.

How it works:

It takes two strings like

> "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

and

> "the quick brown coyote jumps over the lazy dog"

It will create match a string up until it meets the first mismatching character in-between the two. The index of this character is designated by base index (`bi`). So in this case `matchStr` is "the quick brown " then it will generate two new strings as `longer` ("coyote jumps over the lazy dog") and `shorter` ("fox jumps over the lazy dog"). Now the `Array.prototype.rotate()` generic method, which i had implemented a while back for another project walks in. `Array.prototype.rotate()` can rotate the array in both directions but in this particular case we will only rotate it in one direction. `shorter` stays static and `longer` gets rotated to find the longest overlapping sub-string.

```
XX: "fox jumps over the lazy dog"
00: "coyote jumps over the lazy dog"
01: "oyote jumps over the lazy dogc"
02: "yote jumps over the lazy dogco"
03: "ote jumps over the lazy dogcoy"
04: "te jumps over the lazy dogcoyo"
05: "e jumps over the lazy dogcoyot"
06: " jumps over the lazy dogcoyote"
07: "jumps over the lazy dogcoyote "
08: "umps over the lazy dogcoyote j"
09: "mps over the lazy dogcoyote ju"
10: "ps over the lazy dogcoyote jum"
11: "s over the lazy dogcoyote jump"
12: " over the lazy dogcoyote jumps"
13: "over the lazy dogcoyote jumps "
14: "ver the lazy dogcoyote jumps o"
15: "er the lazy dogcoyote jumps ov"
16: "r the lazy dogcoyote jumps ove"
17: " the lazy dogcoyote jumps over"
18: "the lazy dogcoyote jumps over "
19: "he lazy dogcoyote jumps over t"
20: "e lazy dogcoyote jumps over th"
21: " lazy dogcoyote jumps over the"
22: "lazy dogcoyote jumps over the "
23: "azy dogcoyote jumps over the l"
24: "zy dogcoyote jumps over the la"
25: "y dogcoyote jumps over the laz"
26: " dogcoyote jumps over the lazy"
27: "ogcoyote jumps over the lazy d"
28: "gcoyote jumps over the lazy do"
00: "coyote jumps over the lazy dog"
```

So we will collect all matched sub-strings for each single character rotated version of `longer` for it's length many times (one complete turn). Once we have length many matched sub-strings, among which we will chose the longest one. So as you will notice at rotate count (`rc`) #03 both strings produce the longest matched sub-string. Which is `" jumps over the lazy dog"` So now we know that in the `shorter` string (which doesn't rotate) the mismatching characters (mismatching sub-string) are the ones at indices 0, 1 and 2. So the start of match is index 3 (`cd.fis`). While for the `longer` it (`cd.fil`) can be calculated as start of match of shorter (`cd.fis`) + rotate count (`rc`). However there may be cases in which the longer sentence has a shorter mismatching sub-string and in that case (think about it) `cd.fil` would be `cd.fis` + `len` - `rc` where `len` is the length of `longer`.

So now that we have the matching sub string at the head, the two mismatching strings and the remaining matching string (up until the next mismatch) it's just concatenating the string into one with necessary HTML mark up. Then we recursively feed the function up until we reach to the end of one of the strings.

I totally don't know if this algorithm is a reasonable approach for this job. I tried some edge cases where it seems to work fine but I might be wrong and it might turn out to be inefficient. What would be your ideas to speed it up?

```js
Array.prototype.rotate = function(n) {
var len = this.length;
return !(n % len) ? this
                  : n > 0 ? this.map((e,i,a) => a[(i + n) % len])
                          : this.map((e,i,a) => a[(len - (len - i - n) % len) % len]);
};

String.prototype.diff = function(s){

  var getBaseIndex = function(s,l){ // returns the index of first mismatching character
                       var i = 0;
                       while(s[i] === l[i] && i < s.length) ++i;
                       return i;
                     },

   findFirstChange = function(s,l){ // returns the first matching substring after base index
                       var fi = len,
                       substr = "",
                        match = false,
                            i = 0;
                       while (!match && i < s.length) {
                         s[i] !== l[i] ? ++i : match = !match;
                       }
                       match && (fi = i); // match starts from this index
                       while (match && i < s.length) {
                         s[i] === l[i] ? substr += s[i++] : match = !match;
                       }
                       return {bix: bi,    // base index : index of first mismaching character
                               fis: fi,    // index of next re match in shorter string
                               fil: fi,    // index of next re match in longer string (will be adjusted later)
                               fss: substr // next matching substring after first mismatch
                              };
                     },

      isThisLonger = true; // true if the string designated by "this" is longer
                bi = getBaseIndex(this,s),
          matchStr = s.slice(0,bi), // the matching portion at the beginning
              long = this.length >= s.length ? (isThisLonger = true, [...this].slice(bi)) // converted to array as the
                                             : (isThisLonger = false, [...s].slice(bi)),  // long string gets rotated 
             short = isThisLonger ? s.slice(bi) : this.slice(bi),
               len = long.length,
        substrings = [],
                cd = {}, // change data !! important
            change = [], // holds deleted and inserted substrings at indices 0 and 1
          nextThis = "", // remaining part of old string to feed recursive call
             nextS = "", // remaining part of new string to feed recursive call
            result = ""; // the glorious result
            
  for (var rc = 0; rc < len; rc++){ // rc -> rotate count
       cd = findFirstChange(short,long.rotate(rc)); // collect change indices
   cd.fil = rc < len - cd.fis ? cd.fil + rc : cd.fis + len - rc;   // adjusted for index of next re match in longer string
   substrings.push(cd);
  }
  cd = !!substrings.length && substrings.sort((a,b) => b.fss.length - a.fss.length || a.fis - b.fis || b.fil - a.fil )[0];
  long = long.join("");
  if (cd) {
    change   = isThisLonger ? [long.slice(0,cd.fil), short.slice(0,cd.fis)]
                            : [short.slice(0,cd.fis), long.slice(0,cd.fil)];
    nextThis = isThisLonger ? long.slice(cd.fil) : short.slice(cd.fis);
    nextS    = isThisLonger ? short.slice(cd.fis) : long.slice(cd.fil);
    change[0] = change[0] && ('<span class = "deleted">' + change[0] + '</span>');
    change[1] = change[1] && ('<span class = "inserted">' + change[1] + '</span>');
    result = matchStr + change[0] + change[1];
  } else result = this;
  result += (nextThis !== "" || nextS !== "") ? nextThis.diff(nextS) : "";
  return result;
};

textOld.oninput = function(e){textNew.innerText = this.value};
textNew.onfocus = function(e){this.select()};
myButton.onclick = function(e){textdiff.innerHTML = textOld.value.diff(textNew.value)}
```

```css
.deleted  {background-color : LightPink;
           text-decoration  : line-through}
.inserted {background-color : PaleGreen}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="textOld" placeholder="Please type something here" rows = "4" cols = "25"></textarea>
  <textarea id="textNew" placeholder="Please edit the previous text here" rows = "4" cols = "25"></textarea>
  <button id = myButton style = "display:block"> Click to get diff</button>
  <p id="textdiff"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried to diff 'the quick brown fox' vs 'he quick brown fox j' and the algorithm seems to fail: [see image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SS8xQ.png)

Comment: Thank you for testing. I guess it does the job. But as i have mentioned in my explanations, "It sometimes produce some multiple consecutive deletion and insertion spans which probably require a second pass to consolidate them under two single delete and insert spans." So yes there is that.

Comment: Well i have to say even though the previous result was technically right it confused me. So i did some rectifications in the code to get better results without doing a second pass. As it seems it's not "totally" perfect but that's the reason i am here for. I hope i am on a track...

Comment: @syb0rg Yes ok and i have inserted a comment for the only guy who had answered, about the change that i am making. I read the link about iterative reviews too .. So do you suggest me to open up a new topic per each rectification in the code? Come on..!

Comment: As the answer you got was more a comment "It's not working as nicely as it should", I converted the answer to a comment and re-applied your edits. I hope you get some nice real reviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well.. I have just finalized the code. I both had to modify the code according to the comments of @konijn and also tuned it to perform much faster. As of now there is no performance issues at all. A huge paragraph can be diffed in just a few milliseconds. I even added a precision factor to the code. The precision factor is a number used to stop the rotation  of the longer string. It designates the minimum length of the substring that we are searching for. It's a value between 2 and 5. For the default text in below code 4 turns out to be ideal. I guess 4 should be ideal in general too.

The major modifications are;

1. Correcting the `Array.prototype.rotate()` according rightful comments of @konijn.
2. I totally changed the sub-string logic. Once i find the substrings to replace i do text diff on them recursively up until i can do no more.
3. No more collecting all sub-strings per longer string 1 char rotation. Only the first one is needed. Then rotate it one by one all the way it's length long and for each tick find the first matching sub-string. Just pick the longest one and set up your change data accordingly.
4. No more rotating the string by one character advances all along it's length many times. Once i get a sub-string no smaller than the precision factor we stop rotation. This is the key to the performance.

The tunings are;

1. All JS functors like `.map`, `.reduce` (which initially had replaced `.sort`) are replaced by their equivalents implemented by `for` loops.
2. All arrow functions are replaced by their conventional function equivalents.

Throughout my tests the algorithm produced solid results. No more getting beyond itself like in the previous versions. So this is as best as it gets from me.

One thing i liked is that, the array rotating thingy has turned out to be super efficient for this job. I will greatly appreciate all ideas to forward this job further.

OK the default text that i have chosen in the code sample below is quite a long one to demonstrate the capacity well enough. Please try it by modifying it or with different texts to check and measure the results.

```js
Array.prototype.rotate = function(n){
 var len = this.length,
     res = new Array(this.length);
 if (n % len === 0) return this.slice();
 else for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) res[i] = this[(i + (len + n % len)) % len];
 return res;
};

String.prototype.diff = function(s,p){       // p -> precision factor

  function getMatchingSubstring(s,l,m){      // returns the first matching substring in-between the two strings
    var i = 0,
     slen = s.length,
    match = false,
        o = {fis:slen, mtc:m, sbs:""};       // temporary object used to construct the cd (change data) object
    while (i < slen ) {
      l[i] === s[i] ? match ? o.sbs += s[i]  // o.sbs holds the matching substring itsef
                         : (match = true, o.fis = i, o.sbs = s[i])
                 : match && (i = slen);   // stop after the first found substring
      ++i;
    }
    return o;
  }

  function getChanges(t,s,m){
    var isThisLonger = t.length >= s.length ? true : false,
    [longer,shorter] = isThisLonger ? [t,s] : [s,t], // assignment of longer and shorter by es6 destructuring
                  bi = 0;  // base index designating the index of first mismacthing character in both strings
    
    while (shorter[bi] === longer[bi] && bi < shorter.length) ++bi; // make bi the index of first mismatching character
    longer = longer.split("").slice(bi);   // as the longer string will be rotated it is converted into array
    shorter = shorter.slice(bi);           // shorter and longer now starts from the first mismatching character
    
    var  len = longer.length,              // length of the longer string
          cd = {fis: shorter.length,       // the index of matching string in the shorter string
                fil: len,                  // the index of matching string in the longer string
                sbs: "",                   // the matching substring itself
                mtc: m + s.slice(0,bi)},   // if exists mtc holds the matching string at the front
         sub = {sbs:""};                   // returned substring per 1 character rotation of the longer string

    if (shorter !== "") {
      for (var rc = 0; rc < len && sub.sbs.length < p; rc++){           // rc -> rotate count, p -> precision factor
        sub = getMatchingSubstring(shorter, longer.rotate(rc), cd.mtc); // rotate longer string 1 char and get substring
        sub.fil = rc < len - sub.fis ? sub.fis + rc                     // mismatch is longer than the mismatch in short
                                     : sub.fis - len + rc;              // mismatch is shorter than the mismatch in short
        sub.sbs.length > cd.sbs.length && (cd = sub);                   // only keep the one with the longest substring.
      }
    }
    // insert the mismatching delete subsrt and insert substr to the cd object and attach the previous substring
    [cd.del, cd.ins] = isThisLonger ? [longer.slice(0,cd.fil).join(""), shorter.slice(0,cd.fis)]
                                    : [shorter.slice(0,cd.fis), longer.slice(0,cd.fil).join("")];
    return cd.del.indexOf(" ") == -1 ||
           cd.ins.indexOf(" ") == -1 ||
           cd.del === ""             ||
           cd.ins === ""             ||
           cd.sbs === ""              ? cd : getChanges(cd.del, cd.ins, cd.mtc);
  }

  var changeData = getChanges(this,s,""),
           nextS = s.slice(changeData.mtc.length + changeData.ins.length + changeData.sbs.length),    // remaining part of "s"
        nextThis = this.slice(changeData.mtc.length + changeData.del.length + changeData.sbs.length), // remaining part of "this"
          result = "";  // the glorious result
  changeData.del.length > 0 && (changeData.del = '<span class = "deleted">'  + changeData.del + '</span>');
  changeData.ins.length > 0 && (changeData.ins = '<span class = "inserted">' + changeData.ins + '</span>');
  result = changeData.mtc + changeData.del + changeData.ins + changeData.sbs;
  result += (nextThis !== "" || nextS !== "") ? nextThis.diff(nextS,p) : "";
  return result;
};

textOld.oninput = function(e){textNew.innerText = this.value};
textNew.onfocus = function(e){this.select()};
myButton.onclick = function(e){
                     var sr = "",
                         so = textOld.value,
                         sn = textNew.value,
                         ts = 0,
                         te = 0;
                     ts = performance.now();
                     sr = so.diff(sn,+precision.value);
                     te = performance.now();
                     textdiff.innerHTML = sr;
                     perfdiff.textContent = "Diffing the above texts took " + (te-ts) + "msecs";
                   };
```

```css
.deleted  {background-color : LightPink;
           text-decoration  : line-through;
           border-radius    : 3px;
           border           : 1px solid coral}
.inserted {background-color : PaleGreen;
           border-radius    : 3px;
           border           : 1px solid forestGreen}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="textOld" placeholder="Please type something here" rows = "4" cols = "25">But much earlier, the night before Luke had gone to London for six months, before the band was named and when Gabe and Eric had been playing solo shows together, sharing a set, backing each other up; back before all this Luke came to Boston to talk about what theyâ€™d accomplish over the next few months, how to deal with Gabe, that he needed guidance and most of all an editor, someone to tell him when an idea didnâ€™t work, to point out the line between good stupid and bad stupid. This meeting was conducted at the first bar, outside on the patio, smoking and drinking, nearly-naked college kids celebrating around them, and they slouched at a table right in the middle of the floor, speaking slowly and with long pauses. Business concluded, they made their way to the second bar, where Eric instigated an arm-wrestling competition with a hipster in a drum major shirt, a Boston hipster, a sorry imitation of the New York standard. They were drinking Mojo, a microbrew from Colorado famous for inducing blackouts and raising bad blood. Eric was smoking outside and just started talking to the hipster, asking him where he got his hair cut, really pestering him about it which okay was pretty obnoxious, suggesting salons and even specific stylists by name, the guy denying that he got his hair cut anywhere, like it just stays that length all the time, even the deliberately shaggy parts over his ears. But then Eric got distracted by this other guy, a friendly guy with a shaved head and a thick neck who was talking about the difference between a punch you see coming and a punch you donâ€™t, how when youâ€™re going to take a punch you shouldnâ€™t tense your muscles, just let the blow bounce off you, your muscle and in Ericâ€™s case fat absorbing the shock of the blow. Eric asked him to demonstrate, and the guy said no way am I going to hit you man, and Eric, with the love of the world, told him well obviously donâ€™t really hit me, Iâ€™m a pussy thatâ€™s only ever been in one real fight. Pull the punch, Eric said, but hit me once in one arm and Iâ€™ll tense it up, hit me in the other and Iâ€™ll keep loose. So the guy hit him in the loose arm and yeah that really wasnâ€™t that bad at all, then in the tense arm and Eric rubbed his arm and said yeah you were absolutely right man that hurts. Then he went back in the bar and was waiting for a drink, Luke talking to Sasha, the Montenegrin expatriate, Sasha saying that the reason he gets so many girls is because he knows which shoes to buy, denies up and down that it has anything to do with his accent because that would be an insult to his inborn ability to choose the right shoes and get girls. Eric got his drink and turned, taking a sip and wiping the bottom of the glass with a cocktail napkin, and there was hipster drum major guy again, with the bad attitude and the hair, puffing his chest which looked all the more ridiculous because of the brass buttons and epaulets on his shirt, and now the guyâ€™s hackles were raised, like you could see him just standing there and bristling, and he asked Eric if he wanted to fight, and Eric said no but I would like to arm-wrestle. Eric has done this before, has challenged people to an arm-wrestling contest in bars, because it is a way of resolving conflict peacefully, because he will probably lose, but graciously, leaving his opponents zero options in terms of impressing people and getting girls. But he also wanted to win if he could, and heâ€™d developed a strategy: do not try to force the opponent to the table, but merely hold him, wearing him down, relaxing the white muscle fibers that provide quick action, waiting until the guy is tired and then finishing him in one stroke. He did this with the hipster but let his arm drop to forty-five degrees and held the guy there, let the hipster think heâ€™s winning, started making bored faces, yawning. The hipster was angry, wanted a rematch, so they went again, and this time Eric let his arm fall to ten degrees and just held it there, thirty-five degrees more insulting, and suddenly the hipster stood up and announced heâ€™d won, which Eric at this point was drunk and belligerent enough to contest. When he stood up to tell the guy that he hadnâ€™t won, to explain it all to everyone, he saw that the place was suddenly full of arm-wrestlers, people paired up and facing off across the narrow tables, guys with beers and one hand in their pockets, smiling, cheering, making jokes about placing bets. They left the bar, Luke and Eric, heading back to the apartment where Linda was probably asleep which meant they could smoke indoors. They got in a cab, Eric swaying across the seat as they turned corners, now extremely drunk, memory-loss drunk, almost never happens. He managed to tell the cabbie where to go and when they pulled up to the apartment he apparently paid the man, I mean the money disappeared, and then he got out of the car but he stumbled a little getting out, dropped some money on the ground, and when he picked up the money it was covered in blood. He looked at his hand, still standing in the middle of Cambridge Street, and the pinky finger on his guitar hand was bleeding, brown stains on his jeans. He couldnâ€™t move the finger. How the fuck did that happen he thought as he followed Luke inside, Luke taking care of everything all of a sudden. (Alison was in Providence, waiting for her boyfriend to get home from his classes at Johnson-Wales, one of the premiere culinary academies in the nation, drinking a Miller High-Life and listening to music, increasingly annoyed.) They went in the back door and Eric leaned against the white frame, leaving a streak of blood, Linda suddenly awake in a bathrobe and asking them both what happened, but they were both far too drunk to explain anything, and in any case neither of them actually knew what had happened. Linda cleaned the wound while Eric stood at the kitchen sink, trying not to pass out. She wrapped the finger in gauze. The next day Eric woke up early even though he didnâ€™t have to work, re-wrapped his hand and Gabe arrived, ready to play, and they got their outfits and got ready and played a show, Eric on the guitar with three fingers, white bandages hanging from his wrist.</textarea>
  <textarea id="textNew" placeholder="Please edit the previous text here" rows = "4" cols = "25">But much earlier, the night before Luke had gone to London for like six months, before the band was named and when Gabe and Eric had been playing solo shows together, sharing a set, backing each other up; back before all this Luke came to Boston to talk about what they'd accomplish over the next few months, how to deal with Gabe, that he needed guidance and most of all a manager, someone to tell him when an idea didn't work, to point out the line between good stupid and bad horrible. This meeting was conducted at the first bar, outside on the patio, smoking and drinking, nearly-naked college kids celebrating around them, and they hung around at a table right in the middle of the floor, speaking slowly and with long pauses. Business concluded, they made their way to the second bar, where Eric instigated an arm-wrestling competition with a hipster in a drum major shirt, a Boston hipster, a poor imitation of the New York standard. They were drinking Mojo, a microbrew from Colorado famous for inducing blackouts and raising bad blood. Eric was smoking outside and just started talking to the hipster, asking him where he got his hair cut, really annoying him about it which okay was pretty obnoxious, suggesting salons and even specific stylists by name, the guy denying that he got his hair cut anywhere, like it just stays that length all the time, even the deliberately shaggy parts over his ears. But then Eric got distracted by this other guy, a friendly guy with a shaved head and a thick neck who was talking about the difference between a punch you see coming and a punch you don't, how when you're going to take a punch you shouldn't tense your muscles, just let the blow bounce off you, your muscle and in Ericâ's case fat absorbing the shock of the blow. Eric asked him to demonstrate, and the guy said 'No way am I going to hit you man', and Eric, with the love of the world, told him well obviously don't really hit me, I'm a pussy that's only ever been in one real fight. Pull the punch, Eric said, but hit me once in one arm and I'll tense it up, hit me in the other and I'll keep loose. So the guy hit him in the loose arm and yeah that really wasn't that bad at all, then in the tense arm and Eric rubbed his arm and said yeah you were absolutely right man that hurts. Then he went back in the bar and was waiting for a drink, Luke talking to Sasha, the Montenegrin expatriate, Sasha saying that the reason he gets so many girls is because he knows which shoes to buy, denies up and down that it has anything to do with his accent because that would be an insult to his inborn ability to choose the right shoes and get girls. Eric got his drink and turned, taking a sip and wiping the bottom of the glass with a cocktail napkin, and there was hipster drum major guy again, with the bad attitude and the hair, puffing his chest which looked all the more ridiculous because of the brass buttons and epaulets on his shirt, and now the guy's hackles were raised, like you could see him just standing there and bristling, and he asked Eric if he wanted to fight, and Eric said no but I would like to arm-wrestle. Eric has done this before, has challenged people to an arm-wrestling contest in bars, because it is a way of resolving conflict peacefully, because he will probably lose, but graciously, leaving his opponents 0 options in terms of impressing people and getting girls. But he also wanted to win if he could, and he'd developed a strategy: do not try to force the opponent to the table, but merely hold him, wearing him down, relaxing the white muscle fibers that provide quick action, waiting until the guy is tired and then finishing him in one stroke. He did this with the hipster but let his arm drop to forty-five degrees and held the guy there, let the hipster think he's winning, started making bored faces, yawning. The hipster was angry, wanted a rematch, so they went again, and this time Eric let his arm fall to ten degrees and just held it there, thirty-five degrees more insulting, and suddenly the hipster stood up and announced he'd won, which Eric at this point was drunk and belligerent enough to contest. When he stood up to tell the guy that he hadn't won, to explain it all to everyone, he saw that the place was suddenly full of arm-wrestlers, people paired up and facing off across the narrow tables, guys with beers and one hand in their pockets, smiling, cheering, making jokes about placing bets. They left the bar, Luke and Eric, heading back to the apartment where Linda was probably asleep which meant they could smoke indoors. They got in a cab, Eric swaying across the seat as they turned corners, now extremely drunk, memory-loss drunk, almost never happens. He managed to tell the cabbie where to go and when they pulled up to the apartment he apparently paid the man, I mean the money disappeared, and then he got out of the car but he stumbled a little getting out, dropped some money on the ground, and when he picked up the money it was covered in blood. He looked at his hand, still standing in the middle of Cambridge Street, and the pinky finger on his guitar hand was bleeding, brown stains on his jeans. He couldn't move the finger. How the fuck did that happen he thought as he followed Luke inside, Luke taking care of everything all of a sudden. (Alison was in Providence, waiting for her boyfriend to get home from his classes at Johnson-Wales, one of the premiere culinary academies in the nation, drinking a Miller High-Life and listening to music, increasingly annoyed.) They went in the back door and Eric leaned against the white frame, leaving a streak of blood, Linda suddenly awake in a bathrobe and asking them both what happened, but they were both far too drunk to explain anything, and in any case neither of them actually knew what had happened. Linda cleaned the wound while Eric stood at the kitchen sink, trying not to pass out. She wrapped the finger in gauze. The next day Eric woke up early even though he didn't have to work, re-wrapped his hand and Gabe arrived, ready to play, and they got their outfits and got ready and played a show, Eric on the guitar with three fingers, white bandages hanging from his wrist.</textarea>

  <br>
  <div style="text-align: center">PRECISION</div>
  <div style="display:table; margin: 0 auto" >
    <div style="display: inline; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: 60%; text-align: center">LESS <<<</div>
    <input type="range" id="precision" style="display:inline" min="2" max="5" step="1" list="ticks" value="2">
    <div style="display: inline; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: 60%">>>> MORE</div>
    <datalist id="ticks">
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </datalist>
  </div>
  <button id=myButton style="display:block; margin: 0 auto"> Click to get diff</button>
  <p id="perfdiff"></p>
  <p id="textdiff"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is the precision the fasted at step 3, but slowest at 4?

Comment: @mix3d I guess when precision is low it wastes time to paint DOM with some redundant replacements wastefuly (i mean all those pinks and greens) and losing a few miliseconds on those... But obviously it's best at 3 as both as performance and the result you have figured.

Answer (score 4):

Great question,

I do not like your `rotate` function;

- While the nested ternary seems brilliant, it reveals a violation of DRY ( you could do this with one map because every negative `n` has a positive equivalent
- An `Array` function should either change the current array or make a new array, your function could do either depending on whether a shift is necessary or not
- Rotation really is achieved by taking a part of the string and putting it on the other end, since JavaScripts provides `splice` and `shift` I would go with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985260/javascript-array-rotate)
- Minor, but your indentation is off in this function and elsewhere, it disturbs the reading flow

I do like that you modify the `prototype` of `Array`. Most reviewers would complain but I have found 3rd party libraries to have sufficient guards nowadays that is no longer a problem.

Inside `diff`:

- I see no good reason to declare `getBaseIndex` with `var`, even worse is that you declared it as an anonymous function. Naming your variables with `s` and `l` is not great, but `getBaseIndex` does not convey at all what the function actually does
- `match && (fi = i); // match starts from this index` shows you know JavaScript, but really an `if` statement is what you should use here
- Same here: `s[i] !== l[i] ? ++i : match = !match;`
- From a naming perspective, spend the effort to have well written variables. `bix`, `fis`, `fss`, etc. etc. are too hard to parse for the reader
- The commenting however, is great. Otherwise I would probably have given up on this review
- `isThisLonger = true;` <- that semicolon just made all declarations under it globals (use http://jshint.com/)
- I like the idea of matching largest matches first, not sure about rotating. If I was asked to fix a bug in this code, I would steal that smart key idea and rewrite the whole thing.

I wrote an alternative, it works slightly different. (I like that your code recognizes the word fox, whereas my code goes too far in finding commonalities)
I think for an extra bonus, the code should go for both the largest match and the largest mismatch, whatever is largest should go forward. My code has some idiosyncracies, feel free to adopt or ignore (like using `~` with `indexOf` or not always using curly braces with `if` statements.)

```js
//The idea is that we try to match the original string, 
//and then we keep on trying to match smaller and smaller strings
//If we try to match 'Attempt', we will match 'Attempt', 'Attemp' ,
//'ttempt', 'Attem', 'ttemp' etc. till 't' 
String.prototype.largestMatch = function largestMatch( otherString ){

  if( otherString.length < this.length )
    return otherString.largestMatch( this );
  
  var matchingLength = otherString.length,
      possibleMatch, index;

  while( matchingLength ){
    index = 0;
    while( index + matchingLength <= otherString.length ){
      possibleMatch = otherString.substr( index, matchingLength );
      if( ~this.indexOf( possibleMatch ) )
        return otherString.substr( index, matchingLength );
      index++;
    }  
    matchingLength--;
  }
  return '';
};

String.prototype.diff = function( newValue ){
  
  var largestMatch = this.largestMatch( newValue ),
      preNew, postNew, preOld, postOld;
  
  if(!largestMatch){
    return '<span class = "deleted">' + this + '</span><span class = "inserted">' + newValue + '</span>';
  } else {
    preNew = newValue.substr(0, newValue.indexOf( largestMatch ) ); 
    preOld = this.substr(0, this.indexOf( largestMatch ) ); 
    postNew = newValue.substr( preNew.length + largestMatch.length );
    postOld = this.substr( preOld.length + largestMatch.length );
    console.log( { old: this.toString(), new : newValue , preOld: preOld, match: largestMatch, postOld: postOld, 
                  preNew: preNew, match2: largestMatch, postNew: postNew} );
    return preOld.diff( preNew ) + largestMatch + postOld.diff( postNew );
  }
};

textOld.oninput = function(e){textNew.innerText = this.value;};
textNew.onfocus = function(e){this.select();};
myButton.onclick = function(e){textdiff.innerHTML = textOld.value.diff(textNew.value);};
```

```css
.deleted  {background-color : LightPink;
           text-decoration  : line-through}
.inserted {background-color : PaleGreen}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
  <textarea id="textOld" placeholder="Please type something here" rows = "4" cols = "25">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</textarea>
  <textarea id="textNew" placeholder="Please edit the previous text here" rows = "4" cols = "25">The quick brown coyote jumps over the lazy dog</textarea>
  <button id = myButton style = "display:block"> Click to get diff</button>
  <p id="textdiff"></p>
</div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `isThisLonger = true;` <- owww terrible... 10x for pointing out. Waiting for the alternative :)

Comment: Counter proposal done.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your very valuable comments. Thanks to your critics, regarding the `Array.prototype.rotate()` i have given some further thought and managed to reduce it to a much logical form (i had asked for it but couldn't get the reply that i wanted http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/132397/105433) As per the `String.prototype.diff()` I believe your algorithm is superior and a proof of an expert approach. Again thanks to you i have managed to modify mine to produce much better results.

Comment: Yet... yours is solid on the results where mine, while producing correct results sometimes it gets beyond itself :). I have also given performance tests and your's turn out to be returning the result in average 40% faster (160ms vs 280ms) in small paragraphs however when i switch to something really big it looks like mine is doing better (115000ms vs 44000ms) Yours : http://www.replit.com/C8Wm Mine: http://www.replit.com/C612/21. I have also checked both on bare Chrome V52 console and the results seem to be consistent. I will insert the modified one here later today.

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as accepted ;)

Comment: I just would like to thank you once more for your kind guidance on several points that i have mentioned previously. Your algo seems pretty slick but it seriously lacks performance and can not be a practical alternative as is. I have modified my code to do be able handle huge jobs properly in just few milliseconds. As i really like your approach I will mark your answer as accepted once you get it do the same job in a more reasonable time frame. May be you can try splitting the paragraph into chunks, get the diff and concatenate them back.

Comment: You are free to mark an answer or not. However, codereview is not meant to rewrite code to production quality, but to enlighten the poster. I think I enlightened you ;)